# Why is my material appearing white instead of the colour of the texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I'm new to blender, making a wood material with a bump experimenting a little bit using the principle shader. My wood appear *white* instead of the *real color*. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: You don't have any texture plugged to shader's *Base Color* (top socket).

Comment: If you use normal or bump map you always have to change the Color Space to Non-Color on the texture node.

Comment: @SergeL  thank you very much

Comment: thank you @FFeller